# Typescript fails to transpile when leaving out spread of undefined {...undefined}

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a typescript project. In some of the typescript files I include a plain javascript/node file called config.js which looks like this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
};
```

When I run `tsc` the transpilation fails with an error that refer to files that import this config.js file. The error seems to point at some typescript type related problem:

```
src/db/index.ts:138:26 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"source" | "command" | "training" | "page"'.

138   await mutateCollection(CONFIG.commandCollectionName, mutateCommandCollection, commands);
```

The error looks like an application level error but what is a total mystery to me is that when I change my config.js to:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
  ...undefined
};
```

The transpilation step succeeds.

The import of the config.js in the typescript file looks like this: `import CONFIG from '../config';`

Now my question is: without knowing anything about my typescript code, how could adding a spread of undefined (`...undefined`) ever cause the transpilation to succeed? As far as I know `{...undefined}` results in an empty object. Is there some weird bug or edge case that I don't know of?

Note: it doesn't matter where in the object I put the spread of undefined: `{ a: 1, ...undefined, b: 2 }` also makes the transpilation succeed, only leaving it out entirely will make it fail.

Comment: Looks like that you intend to ask a general question (which I think is allowed? Can't find a consensus on that), but usually in order to make sure that the question is answerable and not too broad, include a [example]. (I don't know much about TypeScript so I can't say if the question is already specific enough in the current state)

Comment: I understand your point. The problem is I can't reproduce it in a minimal form. Its also very hard to track down what is happening during a transpilation process. I was just hoping somebody could tell me what potential side affects of using `{...undefined}` could be that might possibly make the transpilation succeed, which might give me pointers to dive deeper into it.

Comment: Please show us where you import that and how you use the object, i.e. give us the code with enough type annotations to reproduce the problem. Probably you should just explicitly state the type of your export and it'll work, TypeScript just was doing too much type inference without the spread element.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce in a web IDE like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)?  I don't know how to help if I can't actually see what you're talking about.  Destructuring `undefined` like that should be a no-op, so if that solution works for you it's probably "fine", but it's so bizarre that it would be better to fix the underlying problem, whatever it is.

Comment: Spreading undefined is invalid in TypeScript. Hard to be sure but it looks like your code is requiring to only have the value "source", "command", "training" or "page" but your object doesn't conform to that shape so there is an error. When you add the ...undefined my guess is that it doesn't try to infer the type as it's not valid TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The people in the comments were right.

If I turn the config.js file into a typescript file with explicit types defined (as can be seen below), then my project transpiles succesfully. It indeed looks like using a spread of undefined (`{ ...undefined }`) causes typescript to not infer the types in the plain .js file anymore and then also not complain about them when used in the typescript files themselves.

An alternative would be to keep using a plain .js file and provide a d.ts file to specify the types.

```
const CONFIG: {
  a: string,
  b: string
} = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}
export default CONFIG;
```